# Automatically select if-else branch in sharepoint workflow

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010

I'm new to SP, so i'm sorry for my question. I need to automatically approve orders every 3 days, depending on their status, which are waiting approval or rejection, but i don't know how to implement this in SP workflow. Do i need to create some type of activity, associated with if-else condition or something? Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a SP Designer workflow, there's a "Pause for Duration" step.  Depending on what your process is, I could imagine a super simple workflow (in addition to the approval workflow) that starts when an item is added, initially waits for three days, then looks at the "approval" column (which is updated via the Approval workflow), then takes care of the "automatic approval" you mentioned using an if-else condition.  But like all things workflow related, initially it sounds simple, but once you start thinking about all the outcomes and scenarios, it gets complicated, quick.

Here's a link describing the "Pause for Duration" option along with some others:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx

Comment: Thank you for reply, popdan! But i don't need to pause my workflow for 3 days. I just want my workflow to waiting for approval from some person and check status of order at the same time, in parallel. Something like http://s017.radikal.ru/i442/1309/be/88c2351d21ca.png

Comment: I was imagining the pause for three days was taking place while other things were happening.    either in its own separate workflow, or as a branch in the main workflow. (not sure what's possible/makes sense) so as the normal workflow actions are taking place, off to the side there's another action taking place that will fire after three days... from your png, it would check order status.

Comment: I resolved the problem. Just have created new EventDrivenActivity and used DelayActivity in it like event. So it works like I supposed.